# Trouble understanding the meaning of sentences with “unless”

Tags: meaning, grammar, conjunctions

I am having trouble understanding the meaning of sentences using *unless*. Here is an example:

> Unless I hear from you by 6pm Friday I will send the letters to main office.

What does the above sentence mean? Are they expecting me to reply?

Comment: *Unless* means *if what follows does not happen*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Unless A, B", meaning, if A doesn't happen, B will happen.

"Unless I hear from you (A), I will send the letters to the main office (B)." This can be rephrased as "if I don't hear from you (Not A), I will send the letters to the main office (B)"

Answer (score 0):

*Unless* = *if ... not.*

If you have trouble parsing sentences like that, use *if* instead of *unless*, and add ***not*** in the other clause.

Hence:

*Unless I hear from you by 6pm Friday, I will send the letters to main office* = *If I hear from you by 6pm Friday, I will not send the letters to main office.*

Answer (score 0):

> Unless I hear from you

has similar (but not *exactly* the same) *logical* meaning as

> If I don't hear from you

The meaning of your whole sentence

> Unless I hear from you by 6pm Friday I will send the letters to main office.

is

> I am planning to send the letters to main office. This will be my default behaviour. The only thing which may prevent me from doing this is hearing from you by 6pm.